# Public domain worldmap image showing Exclusive Economic Zones (water around islands etc)

Tags: data-request, geospatial, oceanographic

I am looking for a **public domain** version of [this image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Internationalwaters.png):

[image: Exclusive Economic Zones]

Requirements:

- Raster or vector image (PNG, TIFF, SVG, etc)
- Public domain (or MIT license, CC0)
- Shows Exclusive Economic Zones of each country separately. For instance, you can tell whether a pixel in the sea "belongs" to USA or Mexico.
- Also shows countries and their limits.

It can also be territorial waters, contiguous zone, or continental shelf, as long as the whole image is coherent.

*(Map above is Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 [Kvasir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Kvasir) at [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/))*

Answer (score 0):

For "GIS territorial waters", one good source is [Marine regions](https://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php).

By clicking the dropdown: "Maritime Boundaries v11", you'll see these datasets, with corresponding links to downloads

- World EEZ v11 (2019-11-18, 127 MB)
- World 24 Nautical Miles Zone (Contiguous Zone) v3 (2019-11-18, 47 MB)
- World 12 Nautical Miles Zone (Territorial Seas) v3 (2019-11-18, 53 MB)
- World Internal Waters v3 (2019-11-18, 55 MB)
- World Archipelagic Waters v3 (2019-11-18, 28 MB)
- World High Seas v1 (2020-08-26, 6 MB)

---

The license seems to be https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/

Comment: My question specifically asks for public domain data, have you managed to find any? Thanks!